# vba Access storedProcedure

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I need to insert data into ms-sql database and I am using stored procedure.

Here is my storedProcedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddHeatPrac] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @HeatNumber varchar(50),
    @RequestID varchar(50),
    @BlendID varchar(50),
    @TrayID1 varchar(50),
    @TrayID2 varchar(50),
    @TrayLoad1 varchar(50),
    @TrayLoad2 varchar(50),
    @TCA varchar(50),
    @NumofTray varchar(50),
    @DischargeRate varchar(50),
    @FurnaceID varchar(50),
    @TProfile varchar(50),
    @TSuction varchar(50),
    @TFlow varchar(50),
    @GasType varchar(50),
    @SS varchar(50),
    @Remark varchar(200)


AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Heat] VALUES (@HeatNumber, @RequestID, @BlendID, @TrayID1, @TrayID2, @TrayLoad1, @TrayLoad2,@TCA, @NumofTray,@DischargeRate,@FurnaceID, @TProfile, @TSuction,@TFlow, @GasType, @SS, @Remark) 



END

GO
```

And this data moves to other table named [dbo].[Heat]
Table's information is like this.

```
USE [RTC_LaplaceD_DEV]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Heat]    Script Date: 2017-08-14 오후 3:17:19 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Heat](
    [HeatNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RequestID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [BlendID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TrayID1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TrayID2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TrayLoad1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TrayLoad2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TCA] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [NumofTray] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DischargeRate] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [FurnaceID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TProfile] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TSuction] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TFlow] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [GasType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SS] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Remark] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

And here is my access code.

```vb
'------------------------------------Connection Setting
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim strConn As String

Dim par As ADODB.Parameter           'input
'Dim introw As Integer

'introw = ListBlend.ListIndex + 1

strConn = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=CHU-AS-0004;DATABASE=RTC_LaplaceD_DEV;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open strConn               'open connection

'------------------------------------Connection Setting
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.AddHeatPrac"
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

    Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@HeatNumber", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextRequestNo.value)
    cmd.parameters.Append par
    Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@RequestID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextRequestNo.value)
    cmd.parameters.Append par
    MsgBox ("TextRequestNo" & TextRequestNo.value)
    Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@BlendID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextH10.value)
    cmd.parameters.Append par
    MsgBox ("BlendID" & TextH10.value)
    Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@FurnaceID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextH13.value)
    cmd.parameters.Append par
    MsgBox ("FurnaceID" & TextH13.value)



    If TextH13.value = "RK1" Or TextH13.value = "RK2" Then
        Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@TCA", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TCA.value)
        cmd.parameters.Append par
        Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@DischargeRate", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, DischargeRate.value)
        cmd.parameters.Append par
        Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@TProfile", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextH14.value)
        cmd.parameters.Append par
        Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@TFlow", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextH16.value)
        cmd.parameters.Append par
        Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@TSuction", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextH15.value)
        cmd.parameters.Append par
        Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@GasType", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextH17.value)
        cmd.parameters.Append par
       Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@SS", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextH111.value)
        cmd.parameters.Append par
        Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@Remark", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextH18.value)
        cmd.parameters.Append par

        cmd.Execute
        conn.Close 'close connection
        Set conn = Nothing
        Set cmd = Nothing

        MsgBox "Succeeded"
        List617.Requery
    ElseIf TextH13.value = "HP1" Or TextH13.value = "HP2" Or TextH13.value = "HP3" Or TextH13.value = "MP" Then
        Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@TrayID1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextH11.value)
        cmd.parameters.Append par
        Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@TrayLoad1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextH12.value)
        cmd.parameters.Append par
        Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@TrayID2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextH110.value)
        cmd.parameters.Append par
        Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@TrayLoad2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextH19.value)
        cmd.parameters.Append par
        Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@NumofTrays", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextH112.value)
        cmd.parameters.Append par
        Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@TProfile", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextH14.value)
        cmd.parameters.Append par
        Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@TFlow", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextH16.value)
        cmd.parameters.Append par
        Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@TSuction", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextH15.value)
        cmd.parameters.Append par
        Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@GasType", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextH17.value)
        cmd.parameters.Append par
        Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@SS", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextH111.value)
        cmd.parameters.Append par
        Set par = cmd.CreateParameter("@Remark", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, TextH18.value)
        cmd.parameters.Append par
        cmd.Execute
        conn.Close 'close connection
        Set conn = Nothing
        Set cmd = Nothing

        MsgBox "Succeeded"
        List617.Requery
    Else
    End If
```

I think there should be no issue, but when I execute my code, I get error saying that 'Procedure or function 'AddHeatPrac' expects parameter '@TSuction', which was not supplied.' After I checked this error, I have double checked my table setting and code. I think there should be no problem but I am stuck in this error.

Would you please help me to solve this error? 
Any comments would be greatly helpful :)

Comment: What is the value of TextH15?

Comment: That is just text box, so any information can be entered in TextH15.

Comment: Could it be NULL?  Please step through in debugger and check what the value is.  If it is TextBox, then why are you not passing TextBox.Text?  I suspect that this is some internal mapping.  Check that your mapping is correct.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock  Value is the most appropriate property for setting or retrieving database values.  The Value property is a variant property that can contain Null and datatypes that match the database.  In this case the mapping is defined in the code already posted with the question, so what do you mean specifically "internal mapping"?

Comment: @janghoyoon  You have two if conditions that assign parameters and call `cmd.Execute`  Does the error occur on both conditions or only one?  Exactly what line does the error occur on?

Comment: @CPerkins Forgive me if I am wrong, but I believe that passing null to a parameter which is not declared as accepting null is treated as though the parameter is missing and generates the error that the OP describes. The Text property again I believe defaults to an empty string Ie is not null. By internal mapping I was thinking along the lines of initialisation: what are the default values assigned to each TextBox, if any. I could have expressed myself better. What I really wanted the OP to check was whether value was null.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock  Definitely I agree that the OP needs to consider Null values.  The table definition explicitly allows Null.  For a natively compiled Stored Procedure it says [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql) that "NULL | NOT NULL:  Determines whether null values are allowed in a parameter. _NULL is the default_."  But this apparently depends on SQL Server version, so it is not completely clear if the parameter accepts NULL.  I understand now about the Text property, but personally I still prefer something like `nz(TextBox.Value, "")`

Comment: @CPerkins That link is very interesting thank you. I need to research this further. I have certainly had problems when assigning null, but now that I think about it, I think the reason is that a .Net null is not a DB null. To pass DB null you need to pass DBNull.Value.